# Why don't I need ampersands with the scanf? (In C)

Tags: c, function, pointers, scanf, ampersand

```
void getnums(int *a, int *b);

int main()   
{  
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    getnums(&a,&b);
    c = a + b;
    printf("a + b = %d\n", c);
    return 0;  
}

void getnums(int *a, int *b)
{ 
    printf("a:? ");
    scanf("%d", a);
    printf("b:? ");
    scanf("%d", b);
}
```

Why don't I need ampersands before the a and b in the scanfs? (The code currently works.)

Comment: If you don't like ampersands, try defining all your variables as 1-sized arrays :) `int i[1]; scanf("%d", i); (*i)++; printf("%d\n", *i);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `scanf` takes pointers as its arguments (so that it knows what variable to modify), and `a` and `b` are already pointers.

Comment: Because of the following line?: 

void getnums(int *a, int *b)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever we `scan` some input it needs a memory location(i.e. address) to store that value, for simple variables we have to use `&` - ampersand - to provide that address.

Here, in function `getnums`, `a` and `b` are pointers so they will already contain address, so no need to write `&` to give the address.